# Laravel form response HTTP 419 when SESSION_DRIVER=database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

My login form was working fine using `SESSION_DRIVER=file` but when changing to `SESSION_DRIVER=database` and trying to log in w/a blade form I always get an HTTP 419.

The login form does have the @csrf token included

```
  <form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin-login') }}">
          @csrf 
            <div class="form-group row">
....
```

Whenever I submit the login form I get this response

```
419 Page Expired
```

### Why it fails: Session CSRF token never matches

I've found that this is happening inside the `VerifyCsrfToken` class `tokensMatch()` method, [the code in Laravel is here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/277c2fbd0cebd2cb194807654d870f4040e288c0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php#L136)

- `$request->input("_token")` is set correctly as the token in the HTML form (from `@csrf` in the blade template)
- `$request->session()->token()` is set to something else entirely, causing `tokensMatch()` to be false

`$request->session()->token()` appears to change on every request.

### Cause? Sessions dont persist for user when logging in

It seems `SESSION_DRIVER=database` is causing the issue. Every request gets a new session `_token`  and all rows in the `sessions` table have `user_id` set to `null`. It seems sessions stored in the database aren't persisting for each user.

Does anyone have a clue how to solve sessions to get them working when `SESSION_DRIVER=database`? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: did you check: the session tables in the db exist. SESSION_DOMAIN config value. The route uses web middleware

Comment: sessions table definitely exists and rows are created but the user_id column is always null. I've tried setting SESSION_DOMAIN or removing it with no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

1. in `session.php` I set "same_site" to "lax"

```
    'same_site' => "lax",
```

2. In Kernel.php the `StartSession` middleware was included in both `$middleware` and `$middlewareGroups` for "web". This was causing it to run `StartSession` twice and overwrite the existing session with a new one for each request. Removing the duplicate in `$middlewareGroups` "web" fixed it.

```
  protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ];

    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
         ------> these two below were the issue. removing them fixed it <------
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        ],
    ];
```

Comment: I had the same problem, and it was caused by laravel/breeze, thanks for the solution.